# Semi Natural language Search using Apache Solr

Tags: java, solr, nlp, opennlp

I did some analysis on Apache Solr and its pretty good to search data from various sources. 
The problem I am facing is how do I standardize my search grammar and translate search text into Solr query.

I have three types of file/database table to search from - namely Customer, Industry and Unit. The first keyword in the search box should be any of the three. After that, the user can define a fix set of criteria:

```
Metrics : 0 or many (ex, exposure, income, revenue, loan_amt etc)
Dimension : 0 or many (Geography, region, etc)
```

Example:

```
customer - Returns all customer data from customer core
customer income from Asia - Returns all customer income details who belongs to Asia 
customer income revenue from Asia - Returns all customer income and revenue details who belongs to Asia
```

How can I translate the above natural language search text to solr query?
Can I fix my grammar of text in Solr like 
first keyword should be customer/industry/unit,
second key-value would be one or more region/geography
and then metric values.

I am not looking for google like search but a limited search where the user knows what to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a Solr question, strictly speaking. As a first step, you might want to define a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) (CFG, type-2 grammar) based on specific production rules for your input. This would give you some solid syntax rules to work from. Based on this, you can then create a parser for the natural language input and map the resulting parse tree to the keyword search in Solr.

Comment: Thanks martin. can you suggest a good Java API/example who can help to define context free grammar.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~zeph/software/JavaCFG/instructions.html

Answer (score 1):

In order not to get sucked into Question answering domain of NLP, which is considered the hardest domain of NLP, maybe try to define a syntax of your questions, for instance X in Y with Z, where X can be different entities like Customer, Y can be some geolocation and Z a filter.